# SX5E option hedge

Tags: options, futures, hedge

There are only quarterly contracts (3,6,9,12) for SX5E futures. In practice, how do we hedge SX5E option at expiry for non-quarterly contracts (say April)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just like any other option.   For example, if you are trading an IBM option, you hedge with IBM stock, which doesn't expire at all, (obviously).

You then sell your hedge in the gamma-storm that enuses at expiry.

For longer term options where you have an expiry that goes way past the futures you have two choices:

1. Trade the rolls periodically
   and/or
2. Exchange some of your delta into longer term swaps

Comment: The fundamental difference between SX5E and IBM is that IBM option are physically settled. So if I long 1 ITM IBM option and short 100 IBM stocks before expiry, then I am still delta neutral after expiry. But SX5E is cash settled.

Comment: Remember, with regular contracts your delta on't be equal to your shares.  You might have 1 contract long IBM hedged by 50 shares short of IBM.   As you get to expiry, the gamma is going to move wildly as you approach the final moment.   You have to trade up to the 100 shares of IBM or get rid of the 50 shares.

Comment: Also, to get help get rid of the delta people will trade the "SQ" in cash.  That would mean selling or buying the basket of stocks on the expiry print.   So you can hedge some of the delta that way and EFP to close.

Comment: That's not what I concern. I 'continuously' hedge the option, so the delta of the position will be zero before expiry if it is ITM and not to close to the strike.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying.   So if you are worried about the fact that you don't have a physical to offset your hedge (derriv), you have to trade the SQ, right?   You'll have setting risk otherwise.

Comment: Let's way I long a SX5E april option contract and continuously hedge it with June future. Suppose it is deep ITM right before expiry, then I would be long 1x april option and short 1x June contract at that time. After expiry the option is cash settled but the future remains. Could you explain a bit more how to trade SQ to eliminate this risk?

Comment: So the problem is that for the option you will only get the margin true up between your last margin setting and the final expiry.  So, you will wind up with a cash credit or debit vs short a future.  Not a very well hedged position.

What you need to do is to buy the stocks at the settlement price.   So you can send orders for all the individual names to the respective exchanges.  That's kind of difficult.

Comment: What's easier is to go to a dealer or the brokered market and ask to buy the future or a swap at the SQ price.   Someone will just sell you the derriv at the setting price leaving you well hedged.

Comment: I am trying to avoid OTC. Trading a combo as synthetic future is also an option but too costly.

Comment: I think you can print the listed future via the brokers.

Comment: Sorry, what is 'print the listed future via the brokers'?

Comment: Go to ICAP or Sunrise and ask for a market int eh SX5E SQ SEP 2021.   They will quote it to you as SQ +/- some basis.   You buy it and then they will print for you the SEP future at the setting price + the agreed on basis.

Comment: The problem is there is no listed SX5E April future. That's why I ask the question. Or is there somewhere else (outside of eurex)?

Comment: Yes, understood.   The SQ trade will be for some other tenor.   So, for example, at SOD your position is:

100 APR .SX5E 80 delta call 
-80 SEP SX5E fut

You buy via a broker 80 SEP SX5E fut for the SQ print

You will wind up hedged.  (no position in this case)

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Of course.    If you need a broker I can recommend a few.